# How can I calculate the inertia tensor of a hollow object defined by a triangle mesh?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, mathematics, mesh

I want to calculate the mass, center of mass, and inertia tensor of player created objects. Some of the objects will be hollow instead of solid. I am creating a closed triangle mesh for their object. Note that this is for a physics building game so I want the values to be as accurate as possible (within reason).

Based on the references listed below, I can get the properties for a solid object by creating a tetrahedron from each triangle of the mesh and calculating the signed volume which gives the mass (volume * density) and the center of mass. I even got the inertia tensor calculation working.

**How do I do the same for a hollow object?**

1. For the mass and center of mass, I am iterating through the triangles of the mesh and totaling their area and calculating the area-weighted average of their positions, then multiplying the surface area by a "density" value to get the mass.

   ```
    public static (float, Vector3) CalculateSurfaceArea(Mesh mesh)
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;

        float totalArea = 0f;
        Vector3 temp = Vector3.zero;

        for (int i = 0; i <= triangles.Length - 3; i += 3)
        {
            Vector3 v1 = vertices[triangles[i]];
            Vector3 v2 = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
            Vector3 v3 = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];
            Vector3 edge21 = v2 - v1;
            Vector3 edge31 = v3 - v1;

            float area = Vector3.Cross(edge21, edge31).magnitude / 2f; // area of the triangle
            totalArea += area;

            Vector3 triCenter = (v1 + v2 + v3) / 3f; // center of the triangle
            temp += triCenter * area;
        }

        Vector3 areaCenter = temp / totalArea;

        return (totalArea, areaCenter);
    }
   ```
2. For the inertia tensor, I am trying a similar approach where I iterate through all the triangles and total up their moments of inertia and using the parallel-axis theorem to account for their positions but **(a) I am not sure this is correct** and **(b) how do I calculate the products of inertia (Ixy, Ixz, Iyz)?**

   ```
    public static (Vector3, Quaternion) CalculateHollowInertiaTensor(Mesh mesh)
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;

        double Ixx = 0f;
        double Iyy = 0f;
        double Izz = 0f;
        double Ixy = 0f;
        double Ixz = 0f;
        double Iyz = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i <= triangles.Length - 3; i += 3)
        {
            Vector3 v1 = vertices[triangles[i]];
            Vector3 v2 = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
            Vector3 v3 = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];
            Vector3 edge21 = v2 - v1;
            Vector3 edge31 = v3 - v1;
            Vector3 center = (v1 + v2 + v3) / 3f; // center of the triangle
            Vector3 offset = center - v1;

            float area = Vector3.Cross(edge21, edge31).magnitude / 2f; // area of the triangle

            // Moment of inertia of triangle rotating around the first vertex
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia
            // I = (1/6)m(P.P + P.Q + Q.Q)
            float triIxx = (edge21.y * edge21.y + edge21.z * edge21.z + edge21.y * edge31.y + edge21.z * edge31.z + edge31.y * edge31.y + edge31.z * edge31.z) / 6f;
            float triIyy = (edge21.x * edge21.x + edge21.z * edge21.z + edge21.x * edge31.x + edge21.z * edge31.z + edge31.x * edge31.x + edge31.z * edge31.z) / 6f;
            float triIzz = (edge21.x * edge21.x + edge21.y * edge21.y + edge21.x * edge31.x + edge21.y * edge31.y + edge31.x * edge31.x + edge31.y * edge31.y) / 6f;

            // Shift to the center of the triangle
            triIxx -= offset.y * offset.y + offset.z * offset.z;
            triIyy -= offset.x * offset.x + offset.z * offset.z;
            triIzz -= offset.x * offset.x + offset.y * offset.y;

            // Shift to the origin (using parallel-axis theorem)
            triIxx += center.y * center.y + center.z * center.z;
            triIyy += center.x * center.x + center.z * center.z;
            triIzz += center.x * center.x + center.y * center.y;

            Ixx += triIxx * area;
            Iyy += triIyy * area;
            Izz += triIzz * area;
            //Ixy += area * center.x * center.y;
            //Ixz += area * center.x * center.z;
            //Iyz += area * center.y * center.z;
        }

        Matrix<double> inertiaTensor = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(3, 3);
        inertiaTensor[0, 0] = Ixx;
        inertiaTensor[1, 1] = Iyy;
        inertiaTensor[2, 2] = Izz;
        inertiaTensor[0, 1] = inertiaTensor[1, 0] = -Ixy;
        inertiaTensor[0, 2] = inertiaTensor[2, 0] = -Ixz;
        inertiaTensor[1, 2] = inertiaTensor[2, 1] = -Iyz;

        Debug.Log(inertiaTensor);

        //Matrix<double> inertiaTensorInverse = inertiaTensor.Inverse();

        // Find the principal axes and simplified inertia tensor
        Evd<double> evd = inertiaTensor.Evd();
        Vector3 inertiaTensorDiagonal = MakeVector3(evd.EigenValues.Real());
        Quaternion inertiaTensorRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(
            MakeVector3(evd.EigenVectors.Column(2)),
            MakeVector3(evd.EigenVectors.Column(1))
            );

        return (inertiaTensorDiagonal, inertiaTensorRotation);
    }
   ```

*References I've been using: (would like some more :))*

- How to calculate the volume of a 3D mesh object the surface of which is made up triangles
  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1406029
- List of moments of inertia
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia
- Polyhedral Mass Properties, David Eberly
  https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/PolyhedralMassProperties.pdf
- Explicit Exact Formulas for the 3-D Tetrahedron Inertia Tensor in Terms of its Vertex Coordinates, F. Tonon
  http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/sciencepublications/jmssp/2005/8-11.pdf